# Convert X and Y arrays into a frequencies grid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, pivot-table

I would like to convert **two arrays** (x and y) into a **frequency** n x n **matrix** (n = 5), indicating each cell the number of point that contains. It consists on resampling both variables into five intervals and count the existing number of points per cell.

I have tried using pandas **pivot_table** but don't know the way of referencing to each axis coordinate.
X and Y arrays are two dependent variables that contain values between 0 and 100.

I would really appreciate some one's aid.
Thank you very much in advance.

This is an example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Arrays example. They are always float type and ranging 0-100. (n_size array = 15)
x = 100 * np.random.random(15)
y = 100 * np.random.random(15)

# Df created for trying to pivot and counting values per cell
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x,'Y':y})

# Plot the example data:
df.plot(x = 'X',y = 'Y', style = 'o')
```

This is **what I have**:
[image]

This is the **objetive matrix**, saved as a df:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not explicitly need to use `pandas` (which you don't, if it's just about a frequency matrix), consider using [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
# Sample data
x = 100*np.random.random(15)
y = 100*np.random.random(15)
```

Construct your bins (since your x and y bins are the same, one set is enough)

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 100, 5+1)

# bins = array([  0.,  20.,  40.,  60.,  80., 100.])
```

**Now use the histogram function**:

```
binned, binx, biny = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [bins, bins])

# To get the result you desire, transpose
objmat = binned.T
```

**Note:** x-values are binned along the first dimension(axis 0), which visually means 'vertical'. Hence the transpose.

Plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

ax.scatter(x, y)
for i in range(objmat.shape[0]):
    for j in range(objmat.shape[1]):
        c = int(objmat[::-1][j,i])
        ax.text((bins[i]+bins[i+1])/2, (bins[j]+bins[j+1])/2, str(c), fontdict={'fontsize' : 16, 'ha' : 'center', 'va' : 'center'})
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: I chose this answer because it seemed to me the easiest one and allows varying 'n', but all answers are fantastic. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)
matching group axes to the center of each grid.
Then you can use [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) to draw them

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(20)


max_val = 100
n = 5
len_group = max_val // 5
x = max_val * np.random.random(15)
y = max_val * np.random.random(15)


# Df created for trying to pivot and counting values per cell
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x,'Y':y})



x_groups = df['X'] // len_group * len_group + len_group / 2
y_groups = df['Y'] // len_group * len_group + len_group / 2

fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 6))

ax.set_ylim(0, max_val)
ax.set_xlim(0, max_val)

df.plot(x = 'X',y = 'Y', style = 'o', ax=ax)
for i, val in df.groupby([x_groups, y_groups]).size().items():
    ax.text(*i, val,fontdict={'fontsize' : 20, 'ha' : 'center',  'va':'center'})
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can just create bins with `pd.cut` and then `groupby` the bins and unstack along the `X` variable and you have a matrix of frequency counts.

```
df['Xc'] = pd.cut(df['X'], range(0, 101, 20))
df['Yc'] = pd.cut(df['Y'], range(0, 101, 20))

mat = df.groupby(['Xc', 'Yc']).size().unstack('Xc')
mat
```

```
Xc         (0, 20]  (20, 40]  (40, 60]  (60, 80]  (80, 100]
Yc                                                         
(0, 20]          0         1         1         0          0
(20, 40]         4         0         1         2          0
(40, 60]         0         0         0         0          0
(60, 80]         3         0         1         0          0
(80, 100]        1         0         1         0          0
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no elegant solution to the plotting part of the problem. But here's what you can do.

```
# Calculate the counts
counts = df.groupby([df.X.astype(int) // 20, 
                     df.Y.astype(int) // 20]).size().astype(str)
# Restore the original scales
counts.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x * 20 + 10, 
                                           y * 20 + 10) 
                    for x,y in counts.index.to_list()], 
                    names=counts.index.names)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Plot the text labels
[ax.text(*xy, txt) for (xy, txt) in counts.items()]
# Update the axes extents
ax.axis([0, counts.index.levels[0].max() + 10, 
         0, counts.index.levels[1].max() + 10])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
# Arrays example. They are always float type and ranging 0-100. (n_size array = 15)
x = 100 * np.random.random(15)
y = 100 * np.random.random(15)

# Df created for trying to pivot and counting values per cell
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x,'Y':y})

ir = pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=20, end=100, closed='left')

df['xbin'] = pd.cut(df['X'], bins=ir)
df['ybin'] = pd.cut(df['Y'], bins=ir)

df['xbin'] = df['xbin'].apply(lambda x: x.mid)
df['ybin'] = df['ybin'].apply(lambda x: x.mid)

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)

for i, val in df.groupby(['xbin', 'ybin']).size().items():
    if val!=0:
        ax.text(*i, val,fontdict={'fontsize' : 20, 'ha' : 'center', 'va' : 'center'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option is to call [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) on [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) of frequency matrix

```
    x = 100 * np.random.random(15)
    y = 100 * np.random.random(15)        
    n = 5
    points = (np.array([x, y]) / 20).astype(int)

    z = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)
    np.add.at(z.ravel(), 
              np.ravel_multi_index(points, z.shape), 
              np.ones(points.shape[1]))
```

Sample run:

```
print(points)
print(z)
[[0 0 0 2 4 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 3 0 0]
 [0 0 1 4 0 4 1 0 1 3 3 1 0 0 3]]
[[3 1 0 2 0]
 [1 2 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```